# Find property of a json key inside schema and update the value accordingly

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, parsing, jsonschema

I have a patch that updates a part of json, The patch contains data in form of operations ('fast-json-patch' style) and some part of data needs to be modified for example concatenated with a prefix.
The JSON schema of this JSON tells which field needs to be modified and is marked with property say `"concatenate":true`
I need to find a way to

1. Find all the properties in the patch that are marked with `"concatenate":true` in it's schema.
2. Update the value of that property before saving

The patch is stored as it is and the operations are used later to be applied, so that's not the concern.
The schema is a problem cause it have references, allOf/anyOf etc conditions, arrays etc and are not managed by me so I can't modify the schema.
Sample input by patch:

```
const operations = 
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/cars",
        "value": "123"
    },
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/bikes",
        "value": [{"speed":123},{"hp":234}]
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/vehicle",
        "value": {
            "brand": {
                "registrationNumber": "123",
                "otherDetails": [
                    {
                        "name": "name1",
                        "value": "value1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "name2",
                        "value": "value2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/vehicle/brand/otherDetails/2",
        "value": {
            "name": "name3",
            "value": "value3"
        }
    }
];
```

I tried the following to retrieve the paths

```
import jsonpath from 'jsonpath';
import { jsonKeyPathList } from 'json-key-path-list';

operations.forEach(element => {
    var paths = [];
    if (!(element.value instanceof Object) && !Array.isArray(element.value)){
        console.log(`Element ${element.path} is on root`)
        paths.push(element.path.replace('/', '.'));
    } else {
        // join "path" and "values" to form a complete json path from root
        jsonKeyPathList(element.value).forEach(e => {
            e = element.path + "." + e; 
            // replace array elements brand.otherDetails.0.name to brand.otherDetails.items.name
            // cause in JSON Schema the array have items so to be able to retrieve easily from schema
            const regexp = new RegExp('\.[0-9]+','g');
            e = e.replace(regexp, '.items');
            e = e.replace('/', '.');
            paths.push(e);
        })
        //console.log(paths);
    }
    var pathSet = new Set(paths)
        console.log(pathSet);
});
```

The above changes provides me following paths for all the operations above:

```
Operation 1 = { '.cars' }
Operation 2 =  { '.bikes.items.speed', '.bikes.items.hp' }
Operation 3 =  {
  '.vehicle.brand.registrationNumber',
  '.vehicle.brand.otherDetails.items.name',
  '.vehicle.brand.otherDetails.items.value'
}
Operation 4 =  {
  '.vehicle/brand/otherDetails.items.name',
  '.vehicle/brand/otherDetails.items.value'
}
```

Now I'm stuck on the schema part. The schema have references, allOf/anyOf etc conditions, arrays etc and I'm not able to think on how to proceed to find all those properties that I found above, check which have the `concatenate` flag and update it in the original operations object

The schema looks somewhat like following:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "cars": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "bikes": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/bikes"
    },
    "vehicle": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "otherDetails":{
         "$ref": "#/$defs/otherDetails"
         }
      }
    }
  },

  "$defs": {
    "brand": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/brand1"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/brand2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "bikes":{
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "speed": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "hp": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "otherDetails": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "brand1": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "otherDetails":{
          "$ref": "#/$defs/otherDetails"
          }
        }
      },
      "brand2": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "manufacturer":{
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "year": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
}
```